# Add custom button in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

We know that the `MPMoviePlayerController` can show a airPlay button in the controller panel if we have a airPlay Device in local network.
The main issue is that I want to develop the airPlay function by myself, is there any way that 
I can put a button beside the original airplay button or just replace it ?